# How can I get append option data?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I got select box option data call from ajax.
like this code.

```
  function fn_callAreaDetail(){
            $("#caArea").empty();
            $("#caArea").append("<option>"+'select your address'+"</option>");
            var selectArea = $("#selectArea").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                data: {
                    comCode : selectArea
                },
                url: "<c:url value="/select/detailArea"/>"
            }).success(function (data){
                for(var i in data){
                    $("#caArea").append("<option value='"+data[i].comCode+"'>"+data[i].comValue+"</option>");
                }
            });
        }
```

and then I want get #caArea option value.
when I submit form this data.
like this.

```
function fn_createCafe(){
            console.log($("select[name=caArea]").val());
            console.log($("#caArea option:selected").val());



            $("#cafeInfoForm").attr("action", "<c:url value="/create/cafe"/>");
            $("#cafeInfoForm").submit();
        }
```

so how can I get #caArea value?

Comment: where do you want #caArea value?

Comment: when I action to form submit.
like this.

            function fn_createCafe(){
                console.log($("select[name=caArea]").val());
                console.log($("#caArea option:selected").val());

                $("#cafeInfoForm").attr("action", "<c:url value="/create/cafe"/>");
                $("#cafeInfoForm").submit();
            }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pure js approach; self explanatory

```js
document.getElementById("button").onclick = getValue;

function getValue() {
  alert(document.getElementById("dropdown").value)
}
```

```html
<select id="dropdown">
<option>11</option>
<option>12</option>
<option>13</option>
</select>

<button id="button">
Find dropdown value
</button>
<p>
click button to see the dropdown value
</p>

<p>
<b>NOTE</b> replace button onclick with your form submit event

</p>
```